# What is incorrect with the following derivations of forward price?

Tags: option-pricing

We understand that the forward price of a stock S is $K=E^{Q_T}[S_T]$ where $E^{Q_T}$
 denotes expectation under the T-forward measure. I have the following derivation that produces incorrect results, but couldn't figure out what is wrong with it. Can anyone help me take a look?

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{split} 
E^{Q_T}[S_T] &= E^{Q}[S_T \frac{P(T,T,T)/P(0,0,T)}{B(T)/B(0)}]  \\
&=E^Q[S_T \frac{1}{B(T)P(0,0,T)}] \\
&=E^Q[S_T] \text{     (assuming constant interest rate)} \\
&=S_0e^{rT + 0.5\sigma^2T} \\
\end{split} \end{equation}$$ $$
\text{B(t) denotes money market account and P(t,S,T) denotes a zero coupon bond. } B(t)=e^{\int_0^t r(u)du}  $$

Comment: For deterministic interest rate, it is true that $E^{Q_T}(S_T)=E^Q(S_T)$, but why $E^Q(S_T) = S_0e^{rT+0.5\sigma^2T}$?

Comment: isnt that the mean of lognormal distribution?

Comment: What is $S_T$ in your case?

Comment: a stock that follows geometric Brownian motion.

Comment: Can you write out the dynamics for $S_t$, and the solution for $S_T$ specifically?

Comment: sure thing. $dS_t/S_t = rdt + \sigma dW$ under the risk neutral measure.

Comment: Then, what is $S_T$?

Comment: stock price at time T

Comment: The specification expression for $S_T$ in terms of $r$, $\sigma$, and $W$?

Comment: i think i figureed out. $S_T = S_0e^{rt - 0.5\sigma ^2 t + \sigma w(T)}$